# To prove $\frac{X+C}{X+D} < \frac{Y+C}{Y+D}$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let, $X,Y,C,D$ all are positive, $X>Y$ and $C>D$. How to prove $\frac{X+C}{X+D} < \frac{Y+C}{Y+D}$?

Comment: Do you have any experience of showing inequalities? Any idea at all?

Comment: Please be careful when stating your question. As it is now, it is still false.

Comment: @mickep. While I appreciate your effort to point put the mistake in the question (thanks for that), but I strongly condemn your manner of asking for any experience in solving inequalities in the comment.

Comment: Why is that? People here will adjust their answers depending on what they know about the methods known to the person who asks the question. That is natural, and please don't take it personally. In fact, asking a question, one is supposed to write what one has tried, and where one is stuck. This is not done here, and I guess that is one reason you have a down vote (not me) on the question. The other might be that it got incorrectly stated twice...

Comment: @mickep.  My objection is,  the way it is asked in the comment "....any experience of showing inequalities? Any idea at all?" I found it very rude. When posting the question, I guessed that in showing inequality I am missing some small trick but at that moment it was not coming to my mind, after several try I posted it here. And the question was downvoted when it was wrongly written. I agree that I should have been be more careful.

Comment: I'm sorry if you were offended by my comment. However, I will continue to ask these type of questions when questions are posed without any effort shown. Next time, show your efforts (even if they do not solve the problem at all) and everybody will hopefully be happy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{X+C}{X+D}=\frac{X+D+C-D}{X+D}=1+\frac{C-D}{X+D}<1+\frac{C-D}{Y+D}=\frac{Y+C}{Y+D}$$

Answer (score 0):

OK, now when the question is properly stated, I edit my answer.

A good idea when showing inequalities involving simple rational expressions, is to move everything to one side, write it on common denominator and factor. Here, the RHS minus the LHS is
$$
\frac{Y+C}{Y+D}-\frac{X+C}{X+D}=\cdots=\frac{(X-Y)(C-D)}{(X+D)(Y+D)}.
$$
You do the work of the $\cdots$. From here it should be clear that the inequality is valid under the conditions assumed.

Comment: Upvoted. you deal with a good argument.